# Route specific IP through networks

Tags: networking, routing

I have a Linux host running Windows in a VM. Host (Net1, IP-B) is connected by WLAN to Router (Net1, IP-A). In this Network is a Machine (Net1, IP-C). Host has a virtual Network card to VM (Net2, IP-X). Finally, Guest is connected to Host (Net2, IP-Y). From Host, I can ping both IP-C and IP-Y).

Guest cannot ping Internet and IP-C as expected.

Now I want Guest to talk ONLY to IP-C. How Do I dot that?

I tried adding a Route on Host

`ip route add IP-C via IP-A` or `ip route add IP-C dev wlan0`

Both did not allow ping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d suggest that you:

1. Configure iptables on Host:

   ```
   iptables -P FORWARD DROP
   iptables -A FORWARD -i Net2 -o Net1 -i IP-Y -o IP-C -j ACCEPT
   iptables -A FORWARD -i Net1 -o Net2 -i IP-C -o IP-Y -j ACCEPT
   ```
2. Enable packet forwarding on Host:

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
   ```
3. Configure a static route to the host on the other machine:

   ```
   ip route add IP-Y via IP-A
   ```
4. Configure a defaut route on the VM (if not already done):

   ```
   ip route add default via IP-X
   ```